# How to find the arrival time of a past flight?

Tags: air-travel, statistics

Where can I find arrival time at BOM airport for below flight? It went from LHR to BOM

BA0199 on 20 December 2012

I searched online quite a lot, but no luck :(

Comment: Scheduled or actual? Because for the scheduled one it might be possible...